# Assigning Angularjs Value to Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I was trying to display a **Map**.

But here I took the values for **Latitude** and **Longitude** `getting from AngularJs`,

How to `assign these values to variable`. Can any one suggest me the solution Please.

Here is my Code.

```
<div>
    <div id="map">
        <script>
            var lat = {{proplist.propagentslattitude}};
            var long = {{proplist.propagentslongitude}};
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <div style="overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:920px;">
            <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:300px;width:920px;"></div>
            <a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.map-embed.com" id="get-map-data">google maps</a>
            <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
            <a class="google-map-data" href="http://www.sparmichl.de" id="get-map-data">sparmichl</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> function init_map() { var myOptions = { zoom: 16, center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }; map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions); marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long) }); infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () { infowindow.open(map, marker); }); infowindow.open(map, marker); } google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I have assigned the `both latitude and longitude` values.

How to assign proper way.

```
<script>
    var lat = {{proplist.propagentslattitude}};
    var long = {{proplist.propagentslongitude}};
</script>
```

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way, integrate it with your angular application so you can pass the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using div.

You can take your angular value in one  
{{proplist.propagentslattitude}}  in your html.

Then in your script just take this value in using document.getElementById('angularvalue').innerText.

```
<div id="angularvalue" style="display:none">{{proplist.propagentslattitude}}</div>

<script>
window.onload=testing ;
function testing(){
var value=document.getElementById('angularvalue').innerText;
alert(value);
}

</script>
```

Now your value will be available for use.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign the values to a variable from template. You should assign this variable from controller.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use a `directive` for this.

The directive will have a google maps service which will hold your'e state(e.g. lon\lat) and it will be your directive's helper for fetching things.

Your'e in the angular world and you should manipulate the DOM **only** from a **directive**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add google maps code in controller and in view file you can just add html. 
review this plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/IBUlwwohxW9IyfJRr6HI/

Better option of course will be to use directive or you can create one yourself aswell.